# Error 404 Object Not Found after successful localhost install of Wordpress. Using Xampp and working on Mac

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working with Xampp and phpmyAdmin and tried to install Wordpress on my computer (Mac). Well, the install was kind tricky but from all accounts it should have worked. After entering database, username, password, and other stuff it successfully installed. However, when i went to refresh (reload), the error message came up (Object Not Found error 404). Cleared the cache, deleted and created a new database in phpmyAdmin and started over again. Once more, it installed successfully but when i tried to access the site (via localhost), the same error message came up again. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: What is the URL that produces the 404 error? Check your Apache error log for more information too

Comment: Had two mySqls running - Apache and System Preference pane. Shut the latter down, up and running.